# Nodejs: Loop not working only gives last id 5 times

Tags: json, node.js, for-loop

I am new here and apologize if this is not right.

So i am trying to loop through a json file in node.
The file contains over 300000 entries where i need to get the id for each and then do something with that ID.

my problem is that my code only return the last ID 5 times:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('big-json');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('read-data.json');
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

parseStream.on('data', function(pojo) {

   for(i in pojo){
       console.log(pojo.id); //This is where i would do something with the returned ID
   }



});

readStream.pipe(parseStream);
```

I have been reading a lot of threads on here and they all say to do the same as I am doing here, but no matter which loop I try it is always the same.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question can be simplified to 'How do I loop through a JSON file?' and if you search Stack Overflow for something along those lines you'll find a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the index to the object inside the loop

```
for(i in pojo){
       console.log(pojo[i].id); 
   }
```

prefer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp)

Comment: If i do this the log comes with Undefined 5 times. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you sure you getting an array of objects or just a single object?

Comment: Well right now it seems like i am getting the same single object (the last one in the file) 5 times

Comment: can you log `i` and see you get 0-4?

Comment: i returns all the objects in the single row of JSON:
adult
id
original_title
popularity
video
so it is not reading everything, except the last line of the document. Which then leads me to a new question: How do i read this line by line, so i can get all the ID's from all of the lines?

Comment: I already did that and this shows Undefined 5 times:

undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined

Comment: try `i['id']` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the of option for looping arrays:

```
   for(let element of pojo){
       console.log(element.id); //This is where i would do something with the returned ID
   }
```

Comment: Hi David, when trying your code i get this:

 for(let element of pojo){
                    ^

TypeError: pojo[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: Probably pojo is not an Array. Can you post what's pojo containing?

Comment: Hi David,
This is what the JSON file contains(over 300000 of these):
{"adult":false,"id":3924,"original_title":"Blondie","popularity":1.61975,"video":false}

Comment: I suppose as an array, isn't it